# Elementary proof on vector algebra

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, vectors

Could you please help me verify my proof for this very basic result in vector algebra? Are these steps, mathematically correct or is there a better way to prove this result?

> *Using the triangle inequality for vectors -*
>
> $$|u+v| \le |u| + |v|$$
>
> *prove that :*
>
> $$|a-b| \ge ||a|-|b||$$

**Proof.**

We have $|u+v|\le|u|+|v|$.

(1) Let $u=a-b$ and $v=b$. Then,

$|a| \le |a-b| + |b|$

$|a-b| \ge |a| - |b|$

(2) Next, let $v = b-a$ and $u = a$. Then,

$|b| \le |a| + |b-a|$

$|b| - |a| \le |a-b|$

$|a-b| \ge |b| - |a| = -(|a|-|b|)$

Combining (1) and (2), we must have :

$$|a-b| \ge ||a| - |b||$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct, but you should get used to put $\implies$ and $\iff$ whenever it is need. For instance: after putting $u=a-b$ and $v=b$, it would have been better if you had written that $|a|\leqslant|a-b|+|b|$ and that$$|a|\leqslant|a-b|+|b|\iff|a-b|\geqslant|a|-|b|.$$